# Vertically align icons and text in a two column layout

Tags: html, css, icons

As you can see in thew image below, all items have different spacing between them and simply look awful. 
This is what I currently have:
[image]

Here is the code (it's a mess) after trying tons of different tricks:
http://pastebin.com/D8ekkj6S

I'd be really thankful if someone could tell me how to properly do this correctly.

PS: If possible, I'd love to know how to vertically align the icon and it's corresponding text by the middle point.

Comment: It is not a good idea to use any inline styling for something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work for you:

HTML:

```
<div class="iconing">
    <i class="icon-someIcon"></i>
    <p>Your text</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.iconing i, .iconing p {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
[class^="icon-"],
[class*=" icon-"] {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
}
```

Replace all instances of 50px with your height.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't use inline CSS. Try using this CSS instead:

```
img {
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

p {
    line-height: 45px;
}
```

For the whole example:
http://jsfiddle.net/VMfYa/

Answer (score 0):

You could also set a bigger line height and set the icon as a background with a padding on the text to keep it away from the icon, or have an icon div and a text div, and float them both left beside each other using margin's to align them properly.

Answer (score 0):

give more width to `p`

check this out [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sachin4dotnet/e6nTp/)